# How to find out the corresponding rpm package names from this python build script output?

Tags: python, rhel-5

I am attempting to compile python 2.6.8 in Redhat 5 linux box.

At the end of the compilation, I got these messages;

```
Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_bsddb             _curses            _curses_panel
_hashlib           _sqlite3           _ssl
_tkinter           bsddb185           bz2
dbm                dl                 gdbm
imageop            readline           sunaudiodev
```

Based on the names above, I used `yum search` and find some rpm packages to fulfill the dependencies

**ncurses**

ncurses-5.5-24.20060715.x86_64
ncurses-devel-5.5-24.20060715.i386

**gdbm**
gdbm-1.8.0-26.2.1.x86_64

**readline**
readline-5.1-3.el5.x86_64

**b2**
bzip2-1.0.3-4.el5_2.x86_64
bzip2-devel-1.0.3-4.el5_2.x86_64

However I cannot do not have luck with the rest them.

Is there any technique in discovering the dependencies? Is there any web resource available to look up the rpm packages?

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to build such an old version of Python? The current versions are 2.7.5 and 3.3.2...

Comment: I am working in a corporate environment and 2.6.x is the 'official' version we use

Comment: I'm sorry about that...

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the `deplist` command to list a package dependencies:

> `yum deplist <package>`

2. Or use the `repoquery` tool from the `yum-utils` package:

> `repoquery --requires <package>`

- Yum man page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum
- Repoquery man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/repoquery

Answer (score 1):

[RPMfind](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/) is going to be your best bet looking for RPMs. Make sure you get the `-devel` versions as well as the main package, as the compiler will be looking for the headers and/or libraries that come in those packages. They happen to have RPMs for Python 2.6.8 on [i586](http://fr2.rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/sourceforge/e/ed/educommons/educommons/eduCommons-4.1.0-final/OpenSUSE_12.2/Python-2.6.8-1.i586.html) and [x86_64](http://fr2.rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/sourceforge/e/ed/educommons/educommons/eduCommons-4.1.0-final/OpenSUSE_12.2/Python-2.6.8-1.x86_64.html) platforms, originally built for OpenSUSE, but potentially useful for you.

As far as Python is concerned, unless you have a specific need for 2.6, I'd *highly* recommend using the most up-to-date, fully bug-patched and feature-filled versions. [2.7.5](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/) is the current release for the maintenance 2.x series, and [3.3.2](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.2/) is the latest version of Python 3. To find info on modules that failed to build, look in the `Python-2.7.5/Modules` directory (or whatever version you end up building) and look for `.c` files related to the module name. For example, in my `Python-3.3.2/Modules` directory, I have `_tkinter.c` which says right at the top "Only Tcl/Tk 8.3.1 and later are supported" so now I know what package names and versions to search for.

Good luck!